# Azure DevOps Rest API in Powershell saying no parameters matching

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am starting to use PowerShell to call the Azure DevOps REST API. But it seems like when I try to add parameters it tell me:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'repositoryId'

Here is what my call looks like in PowerShell. If I take out the parameter it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1' -repositoryId $repoId -Headers (my authentication) -Method Get
```

Per Microsoft's documentation this should work. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**repositoryId** should be url parameter as Booga Roo mentioned. The error indicated that **Repository type** is missing.

You should add another parameter to your uri `repositoryType={repositoryType}`.So the uri should be like below.

**Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.webapi.repositorytypes?view=azure-devops-dotnet) for all repositoryTypes**

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_apis/build/builds?repositoryId={id}&repositoryType=TfsGit&api-version=5.1
```

**Addition:**

You can get your **repositoryId** from URL of **Repositories** page under **Repos** in the **Project Settings**. Check below screentshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet does not have a `-repositoryId` parameter. The phrasing and examples on the help page are for "URI Parameters" instead of PowerShell parameters. It means you need to build it into `-Uri` value instead of trying to use it directly.

I suggest using this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?repositoryId={$repoId}&api-version=5.1" -Headers (my authentication) -Method Get
```

Side note: There are double quotes around this example URI. This is so the variable expansion for $repoId will occur and be properly interpreted as part of the URI. Using single quotes as in the original example will prevent this and treat it as a literal string value and won't perform any subsitutions.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and that is what I initial tried but I get "Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Repository type is missing/invalid.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.RepositoryInformationInvalidException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"RepositoryInformationInvalidException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}"

Comment: I don't have an instance to test against a the moment, but I would expect that means that the repo ID is either incorrect, mis-formatted, unexpanded, missing, or you don't have permissions to that particular repo. However, since you said it works without using the parameter, I would imagine you do have permissions. So, if you check the value of `$repoId` does it return what you expected?

Comment: @Nathan There was also a missing ampersand in the URI example above. Hopefully you noticed, but it has been updated to add that in the example.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It seems putting quotes around my RepositoryType was my problem. It is now not throwing errors and showing me results I expect. Thank you all for your help!